# Unable to deploy my Laravel 9 app into IIS sub-folder

Tags: laravel, iis, windows-server-2016

I always get 404 error:

`GET https://example.com/favicons/favicon-16x16.png   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]` while the correct path must be `https://example.com/cms/favicons/favicon-16x16.png`

While it works fine in case I deployed the app under root folder

May you please help me?

- URL Rewrite and FastCGI aleady configured
- Already added my app as Virtual Directory into `https://exmaple.com/cms`

  - physical path: `c:\LaravelApp\public`
  - virtual path: `/cms`
- `.env` already configured as `APP_URL=https://exmaple.com/cms`

I suspect this issue related to Rewrite but I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem (googled a lot)

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2-1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.